# difference between protoloader and generated .js files from grpc

Tags: grpc

I am a beginner in GRPC and nodejs.
For the first time, I use protoloader to load my services from proto. Then, I want to switch to use generated files from grpc: in my case I have: comment_pb.js, So I replace this code with:

```js
    import protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
    
    const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('../../../protos/comment.proto', {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        arrays: true
      });
    
      //pass proto in grpc 
      var commentProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
```

with:

```js
    import protoLoader from './proto/comment_pb.js';
```

I don't know what's the diff between these two methods, does this change the rest of the code? there are any helpful links about this.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC [Node Basics tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/basics/) goes through through a [`dynamic_codegen`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.34.1/examples/node/dynamic_codegen) example, but there's also a very similar-looking [`static_codegen`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.34.1/examples/node/static_codegen) example. It should be useful to go through them and compare them to understand the difference in the static and dynamic approaches.